# Does this query assign a new label to the node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (a:Artist) 
WHERE a.name in ['Kate Bush', 'Loney Dear', 'Robbie Williams', 'Robyn', 'Amanda Fondell', 'James Blunt'] 
SET a:EmilFave
RETURN a
```

This query returns a list of artists, and then it sets a label 'EmilFave'. Does this mean it adds an additional label to node of Artist? What's the purpose of doing this typically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it adds an additional label to the nodes matched in that query. In this case, it was to indicate the subset of artists in the graph that are Emil's favourites.

In subsequent queries that need to deal with only Emil's favourite artists, there's now no need to filter on all artists by `WHERE a.name in ['Kate Bush', 'Loney Dear', 'Robbie Williams', 'Robyn', 'Amanda Fondell', 'James Blunt']` and instead, the query is constrained to nodes which have the `EmilFave` label (leading to a more efficient query)